# CasperJS upload image from url instead of server path

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to do my automation things. But for file uploading, I upload images from other website using `exec()` and `wget` to my server, then use CasperJS and `casper.uploadFile()` to post images on website.

Now I trying to post image using website image URL, I mean:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.uploadFile("input[type='file']", '/var/tmp/img.jpg');
})
```

but I want to do:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.uploadFile("input[type='file']", 'http://mywebsite.com/images/img.jpg');
})
```

and when I did that Casper just fails.

Comment: As you probably have guessed yourself, it won't work. When filling upload fields browsers use local files.

Comment: Yes exactly, I just think that there is something like a read-write stream, as we have in Node itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not download the image first then upload it?

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.download("http://mywebsite.com/images/img.jpg", 'd:/_tmp/img.jpg');
}

casper.then(function(){
  this.uploadFile("input[type='file']", 'd:/_tmp/img.jpg');
})
```

See [download](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) from the docs